# who are the best of brahmins?

Tags: gita

Gita Verse 7 chapter 1

asmākaṁ tu viśhiṣhṭā ye tānnibodha dwijottama

nāyakā mama sainyasya sanjñārthaṁ tānbravīmi te

Meaning :O best of Brahmins, hear too about the principal generals on our side, who are especially qualified to lead. These I now recount unto you.

Im not getting  here  who  are the  **best of brahmins**?  I mean to whom it talking about ?

Comment: Misquote
मय्यासक्तमनाः पार्थ योगं युञ्जन्मदाश्रयः।
असंशयं समग्रं मां यथा ज्ञास्यसि तच्छृणु।।7.1।।
The Blessed Lord said O Arjuna, hear how you shall without doubt know Me fully, with the mind intent on Me, practising Yoga and taking refuge in Me.

Comment: It is King Duroyodhana addressing his teacher, Drona.

Comment: It's a way of referring/addressing to someone, respectfully. A salutary sobriquet, if you'll. For ex: All the divinities are given various elegant sobriquet when praised. (Thou art the ruler of all worlds, Thou art the indestructible eternal soul, thou art Source of everything)

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru OP is talking about 1.7